# Add an anchor to an attached file in ITextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I was able to add an attachment to my PDF:

```
 PdfFileSpecification specification = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(writer, name, name, null);
 writer.AddFileAttachment(specification);
```

But now I would like to add something like a reference to this file in the text of my PDF. Is it possible that if a click that "link" the file is opened?

===EDIT===

According to the answer i also tried the following:

```
PdfFileSpecification specification = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(writer, name, name, null);
PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.CreateFileAttachment(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(100, 200), "Link", specification);
chapter1.Add(annotation);
```

This adds the file to the document, and also writes the filename to the document, but it's not linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PDF](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) supports "embedded go-to actions" for PDFs within PDFs.  If you're embedded file isn't a PDF, that won't work... and it doesn't look like iText supports them at a higher level.  You'd have to mess with the PdfAction's dictionary directly.  Given that your previous question was about an audio file, I'm going to guess "no, that won't work".

PDF also supports "embedded file annotations".  As does iText.  `PdfAnnotation.createFileAttachment()`.  One of the overrides takes a `PdfFileSpecification`.

Clicking on an embedded file annot gives the user the option to open the file or save it.  I think that's as close as you're gonna get.

Comment: thanks a lot, I tried that but it doesnt seem to work. But I also don't know whats the rectangle that i have to pass.